# How to use Qt GUI (created with Qt Designer) in perl?

Tags: perl, qt

I have created Qt GUI in Qt Designer and compiled it (using puic4) to gui.pm. 
Now, I'd like to use it in my Perl application, but I'm stuck because I don't know how to create window object.

I have following code in start.pl:

```
use strict;
use QtCore4;
use QtGui4;
use gui; #compiled gui ('Ui_MainWindow' package)

my $a = Qt::Application(\@ARGV);
my $w = ??? #assign window object to $w

$w->show();
exit $a->exec();
```

I just need to create window object, but I can't find any example written in perl. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution in the source repository:

```
BUILD_DIR/Qt4-0.99.0/qtgui/examples/designer/calculatorform
```

1. Build your Ui-Module

```sh
 > puic4 Window.ui -o Ui_MainWindow.pm
```

```perl
#################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'Window.ui'
##
## Created: Do. Aug 27 20:57:17 2015
##      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.8.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

package Ui_MainWindow;

use strict;
use warnings;
use QtCore4;
use QtGui4;

sub centralwidget {  return shift->{centralwidget}; }
sub pushButton {  return shift->{pushButton}; }
sub pushButton_2 { return shift->{pushButton_2}; }
sub menubar { return shift->{menubar}; }
sub statusbar { return shift->{statusbar}; }

sub setupUi {
   my ( $class, $mainWindow ) = @_;
   my $self = bless {}, $class;
   if ( !defined $mainWindow->objectName() ) {
       $mainWindow->setObjectName( "mainWindow" );
....
```

2. Create a launch module MainWidow.pm. You have to "cast" the UI-class.

```perl
package MainWindow;
use strict;
use warnings;
use QtGui4;
# Cast the exact Qt Type for your UI class
use QtCore4::isa qw( Qt::MainWindow );

use Ui_MainWindow;

sub NEW {
  my ( $class, $parent ) = @_;
  $class->SUPER::NEW($parent);
  this->{ui} = Ui_MainWindow->setupUi(this);
}
```

3. Write the application perl script Main.pl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use QtCore4;
use QtGui4;
use MainWindow;

sub main {
   my $app = Qt::Application( \@ARGV );
   my $win = MainWindow();
   $win->show();
  exit $app->exec();
}

main();
```

regards huck

Comment: Can I run this code in linux?

Answer (score 2):

Pretend that I don't know about QTDesigner , which example from http://search.cpan.org/dist/Qt/MANIFEST would you follow?
I think , you pick one of the .ui examples, run the makefile (or by hand), and then you have a module you can call (ie `my $w = my $chat = ChatMainWindow();` ).