# What is a good resource/method for me to learn making Qt GUIs for Perl?

Tags: perl, qt, user-interface

I am decent with Perl, and I've chosen to start learning making GUI interfaces for my Perl programs. That said, I've found it hard to learning how to make a GUI with Qt. I have the bindings from http://code.google.com/p/perlqt4 which seem to be the most recent, but as to how to use them I'm still a bit stumped. All the books and tutorials on the net that I can find are either geared towards using Qt with C++ or with Python.

I'm an absolute Qt beginner and would like to learn how to use it with Perl, but unfortunately the net seems scarce on material for me to use. I can make a GUI design with QtDesigner but don't know how I can fit the code that it generates together with Perl. I can copy the examples from http://code.google.com/p/perlqt4/source/browse/qtgui/examples/tutorial , but those are simple programs withe no accompanying documentation that would allow me to know what is going on or why the code was written that way.

I don't know how Qt or the bindings work but I'd like to learn. Everything that I can find is either obsolete or written for bindings for other languages which I don't understand. I was hoping that some people who've already done this would give me some solid advice or point to some good resources so that I could start learning.

Comment: Qt + Perl is a horrible mess. It's really sad that the one of the best toolkits ever has no decent Perl bindings. While it's fairly easy to follow the C++ documentation and translate that to Perl, the bindings themselves are a major version behind, incomplete, and most importantly hard to install. If you want a less frustrating experience, look at the GTK bindings, or completely ditch GUIs and only write for the command line or the web. Considering the state of the web, that's actually a viable option.

Comment: I'd recommend python if you want scripting language + Qt.

Answer (score 0):

If making a GUI is what you want to do, please consider [CitrusPerl](http://www.citrusperl.com) that builds on top of [wxPerl](http://www.wxperl.it) which is nothing more than a wrapper around [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org). It also makes it very easy to create installers or packagers with the use of [Cava Deployment Tools](http://www.cavapackager.com).

**TIMTOWTDI**

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a further day with the stuff qt4 + perl ..it works in [that (stackexchange)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32258223/33386) way. I use a standard debian wheezy distribution with the packages libqtcore4-perl and libqtgui4-qt etc. Sources from Chris Burel can be found under [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~cburel/Qt4-0.99.0/) or [GIT](https://github.com/chrisburel/perlqt4). Regards